# What are the business ledgers used for?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Across my travels I've come across 2 business ledgers. I can't remember where the first one was (I think it was some sort of shop or a jarl's room), I found the second one in the stable house.

Both of them had the following tooltip when moused over "Forge Numbers Business Ledger". Both times I attempted to use them a message popped up "There's nothing to change in the ledger".

What do I have to do to be able to use it, and what does it do when I do use it?

Comment: My bet is on one of the thieves guild misc. quests.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once you officially join the Thieves' Guild, you'll be able to pick up additional jobs from Devin Mallory and Vex: they'll assign you one of seven types of random quests for you to do.

One of the quests, *The Numbers Job*, will task you with forging/modifying a random business ledger throughout the world. That's what you need them for.

Outside of that, they're not used.